# Show existence of the object instead of retrieving it in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Supposed we have this object in mongodb:

```
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "result: [
       {"result1": "somthing"},
       {"result2": "else"}
   ]
}
```

I want to query in the way which if result exist I get this:

```
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "result": true
}
```

and if it does not exist get this:

```
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "result": false
}
```

In my project result is pretty big object and on my result list, I just want to show if it has result or not (user can get more details by click on something).

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by *"the result exist"*. That could either mean the "result" field itself or possibly an element within the "result" array that you want to test for. At any rate, the only methods with MongoDB that return anything other than the existing content are `mapReduce` and `aggregate`. And it's generally overkill to ask the server to do work like that unless you really are producing a much smaller document as a result of the alteration.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution:  This works from the mongo shell:

```
db.collectionName.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.result = (doc.result && doc.result.length > 0)?true:false;
    print(tojson(doc));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think it's efficient. I don't want to retrieve huge result object (>4K) from MongoDB. I want to have something equivalent inside of MongoDB not in Javascript.